# Find wifi strength using python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am writing  software for a Raspberry Pi based robot device.
I want the robot to stop and react when it moves too far from the wifi transmitter before it loses signal completely.

Is there an easy way in Python to get a value of the strength or quality of the current wifi connection so I can monitor this?

Comment: Try iwlist - Get more detailed wireless information from a wireless interface. https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwlist.  good source code here  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=85601

Comment: A little googling can go [a long way](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=85601).

Comment: But does it work during an active connection or only when disconnected?